# Disable Retry When commitInterval = 1

Tags: spring-batch

The behavior for the batch processing of our business entities we would like is to rollback the failed transaction and not try again. I have read through the forum and it appears that it is not possible. We have set the commitInterval=1 and tried the Never Retry Policy for this special case but to no avail. I have read the rational is that the writer does not know if the list of items received is the initial or subsequent processing in the case of a failure.

Have I summarized this correctly and Spring batch does not currently support the behavior we are looking for?

Comment: please post the complete job configuration, the behaviour you describe should happen while using skip

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a candidate for Skip Logic

https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/configureStep.html

Check out these two sections in particular:

- 5.1.5 Configuring Skip Logic
- 5.1.7 Controlling Rollback